# How to sub-string in SQL with 4 same consecutive characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sub-string `11.1.2.3.4.5` or `10.1.2.4.5` and so on to be split until 4(dot) only like `11.1.2.3` and `10.1.2.3` likewise.

Can someone help to achieve this in SQL?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: What baout your attempt with `SUBSTRING` didn't wpork?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recurcive CTE  as the following

```
CREATE TABLE Strings( S VARCHAR(25) );

INSERT Strings VALUES
('1.2.3.4.5.6'),
('11.2.12.5.66'),
('y.888.p.666.2.00');

WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 1 N, CHARINDEX('.', S) Pos, S
  FROM Strings 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT N + 1, CHARINDEX('.', S, Pos + 1), S
  FROM CTE
  WHERE Pos > 0
)
SELECT S, SUBSTRING(S, 1, Pos - 1) --or use LEFT()
FROM CTE
WHERE N = 4;
```

Or using a nested `CHARINDEX()` as

```
SELECT S, LEFT(S, CI-1)
FROM Strings
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
  (CHARINDEX('.', S, CHARINDEX('.', S, CHARINDEX('.', S, CHARINDEX('.', S)+1)+1)+1))
) T(CI)
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80f11f8b37a57b462664a8bdf6d560ba)